# Prove that $\sqrt[n]{a_1}-\sqrt[n]{a_2}+\sqrt[n]{a_3}-\dots-\sqrt[n]{a_{2n}}+\sqrt[n]{a_{2n+1}}<\sqrt[n]{a_1-a_2+a_3-\dots-a_{2n}+a_{2n+1}}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Question:

> Prove that $\sqrt[n]{a_1}-\sqrt[n]{a_2}+\sqrt[n]{a_3}-\dots-\sqrt[n]{a_{2n}}+\sqrt[n]{a_{2n+1}}<\sqrt[n]{a_1-a_2+a_3-\dots-a_{2n}+a_{2n+1}}$ where $n$ and $\{a_i\}$ are reals and $n\geq2$ and $0<a_1<a_2<a_3<\dots<a_{2n+1}$.

This is a Math Olympiad question for $7$~$8$th-graders.

My attempt:

The restriction $0<a_1<a_2<a_3<\dots<a_{2n+1}$ makes the question really hard. The only inequalities that work are Jenson's and Karamata's. However, Jenson's does not work here as the weights ($1, -1, 1, -1, \dots$) are not all positive. Karamata's does not work here either as there are only $1$ sequence $\{a_i\}$.

I tried raising both sides to a power of $n$ to try and simplify the expression but it did not help.

$$
\sqrt[n]{a_1}-\sqrt[n]{a_2}+\sqrt[n]{a_3}-\dots-\sqrt[n]{a_{2n}}+\sqrt[n]{a_{2n+1}}<\sqrt[n]{a_1-a_2+a_3-\dots-a_{2n}+a_{2n+1}} \\
\iff (\sqrt[n]{a_1}-\sqrt[n]{a_2}+\sqrt[n]{a_3}-\dots-\sqrt[n]{a_{2n}}+\sqrt[n]{a_{2n+1}})^n<(\sqrt[n]{a_1-a_2+a_3-\dots-a_{2n}+a_{2n+1}})^n \\
\iff a_1-a_2+a_3-\dots-a_{2n}+a_{2n+1}+\text{*ugly expression*}<a_1-a_2+a_3-\dots-a_{2n}+a_{2n+1}
$$

How can I do this question? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csqrt%5Bn%5D%7Ba_1%7D-%5Csqrt%5Bn%5D%7Ba_2%7D%2B%5Csqrt%5Bn%5D%7Ba_3%7D-%5Cdots-%5Csqrt%5Bn%5D%7Ba_%7B2n%7D%7D%2B%5Csqrt%5Bn%5D%7Ba_%7B2n%2B1%7D%7D%3C%5Csqrt%5Bn%5D%7Ba_1-a_2%2Ba_3-%5Cdots-a_%7B2n%7D%2Ba_%7B2n%2B1%7D%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%240%3Ca_1%3Ca_2%3Ca_3%3C%5Cdots%3Ca_%7B2n%2B1%7D%24&p=1), there's the AoPS threads [Plus minus inequality by enescu](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h85155p495395) (which says it's from "Balkan MO $1998$, Problem $2$") ...

Comment: (cont.) and [a1,a2,...,an](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1529764p9193548).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, since $\sqrt[n]{x}$ is concave, by properties of concavity (or by Karamata's Inequality), we have that

$$
\sqrt[n]{a_{2n+1}}-\sqrt[n]{a_{2n}}<\sqrt[n]{a_{2n+1}-a_{2n}+a_{2n-1}}-\sqrt[n]{a_{2n-1}} \\
\implies -\sqrt[n]{a_{2n}}+\sqrt[n]{a_{2n+1}}<-\sqrt[n]{a_{2n-1}}+\sqrt[n]{a_{2n+1}-a_{2n}+a_{2n-1}}
$$

Hence, we have

$$\begin{align}
\text{LHS} 
&<\sqrt[n]{a_1}-\sqrt[n]{a_2}+\sqrt[n]{a_3}-\dots-\sqrt[n]{a_{2n-2}}+\sqrt[n]{a_{2n-1}-a_{2n}+a_{2n+1}}  \\
&<\sqrt[n]{a_1}-\sqrt[n]{a_2}+\sqrt[n]{a_3}-\dots-\sqrt[n]{a_{2n-4}}+\sqrt[n]{a_{2n-3}-a_{2n-2}+a_{2n-1}-a_{2n}+a_{2n+1}} \\
&\dots \\
&<\sqrt[n]{a_1-a_2+a_3-\dots-a_{2n}+a_{2n+1}}=\text{RHS}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 4):

To prove this using OP's ideas:

1. Show that $f(x) = \sqrt[n](x)$ is a concave function.
2. Show that $f(a_1) + f(a_3) < f(a_2) + f(a_1-a_2+a_3)$ for $a_1 < a_2 < a_3$.

   - This should be "obvious" from a visual graph. To formally prove it, use Jensen's, applied to a weighted average
   - Show that $f(a_2) = f(\frac{(a_2 - a_1)a_3 + (a_3 - a_2)a_1 } { a_3 - a_1}) > \frac{a_2 - a_1}{a_3 - a_1} f(a_3) + \frac{a_3 - a_2}{a_3-a_1} f(a_1). $.
   - Show that $a_1 < a_1 - a_2 + a_3 < a_3$.
   - Find a similar inequality for $f(a_1 - a_2 + a_3)$.
   - Add up these 2 inequalities.
3. Recognize that we can induct on the number of terms $a_1, a_2, \ldots a_{2m+1}$.

   - Assume it is true for some $m$. For some increasing sequence $\{b_i\}_{i=1}^{2m+3}$, consider  $a_1 = b_1 - b_2 + b_3$ and $a_i = b_{i+2}$ for $i = 2$ to $2m+1$.
   - Show that $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^{2m+1}$ is an increasing sequence  so we can apply the induction hypothesis
   - Show that $\sum (-1)^{i+1} f(b_i) < f(b_1 - b_2 + b_3) - f(b_4) + \ldots f(b_{2m+3} ) < f( \sum(-1)^{i+1} b_i)$.